# Scala: Matching vararg (repeating arguments) by type of stored elements

Tags: scala, types, arguments, repeat, variadic-functions

I recently started learning Scala and am currently messing around with tutorials. I'd like to have 2 implementations of Rational Arithmetics. I have trait IRational and 2 classes implementing it: Rational and RationalAbstraction. Most of the functionality is the same so I implement default behavior in trait but I need to get the correct constructor - either for Rational or RationalAbstraction. To this end I have a function:

```scala
def constructorImpl(numerator: Int, denominator: Int, first: IRational, irationals: IRational*): IRational = {
  println(s"first class: ${first.getClass.getSimpleName}, irationals class: ${irationals.getClass.getSimpleName}")
  first match {
    case rational: Rational => irationals match {
      case rationals: Seq[Rational] => new Rational(numerator, denominator)
      case _ => throw new UnimplementedCaseException(this, "constructorImpl", first +: irationals: _*)
    }
    case abstraction: RationalAbstraction => irationals match {
      case abstractions: Seq[RationalAbstraction] => new RationalAbstraction(numerator, denominator)
      case _ => throw new UnimplementedCaseException(this, "constructorImpl", first +: irationals: _*)
    }
  case _ => throw new UnimplementedCaseException(this, "constructorImpl", first +: irationals: _*)
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.
`case rationals: Seq[Rational] => new Rational(numerator, denominator)`
Does not match varargs containing Rational, allows also RationalAbstraction.
Why is that? 
How to match varargs by type?
Do I need to write function that unwraps irationals: _* one by one and check the head's (first elements') type?

This is the project github repository: 
https://github.com/axal25/LearnScalaMavenBasics

Call to the function test case [256 line]:
https://github.com/axal25/LearnScalaMavenBasics/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/exercises/scala/ool/ObjectOrientedProgramming.scala

Function implementation [106 line]:
https://github.com/axal25/LearnScalaMavenBasics/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/exercises/scala/ool/arith/ration/IRational.scala

If someone has some good example material (tutorial) illustrating how those damn pesky varargs work in Scala I'd be grateful.

Edit:
The purpose of the `constructorImpl` method is to pick the correct constructor for arithmatic operations (add/+, sub/-. mul/*, div//).
`first: Irational` argument is 1st argument of the operation (add, sub, mul, div).
`irationals: Irational*` argument is 2nd, 3rd, ... n-th argument of the operation (add, sub, mul, div).
Some operations require 2 objects of IRational implementation, some require 1 object of IRational impl. and for example Int, but always at least 1 IRational impl object. So picking the correct constructor depends on those IRational impl objects and requires that they both are of the same implementation. If 2 (or more) objects of IRational implementation are of different implementation (combination of Rational and RationalAbstraction) we don't know what constructor to call, so there should be exception thrown.

The solution in this hierarchy (without using generics):

```scala
  def constructorImpl(numerator: Int, denominator: Int, first: IRational, irationals: IRational*): IRational = {
    println(s"first class: ${first.getClass.getSimpleName}, irationals class: ${irationals.getClass.getSimpleName}")

    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def isSeqElementsOfTypeSameAsFirst(first: Any, irationals: Any*): Boolean = irationals match {
      case Seq() => true
      case Seq(head, tail@_*) => {
        if (first.getClass == head.getClass) isSeqElementsOfTypeSameAsFirst(first, tail: _*)
        else false
      }
      case _ => false
    }

    if (isSeqElementsOfTypeSameAsFirst(first, irationals: _*)) {
      first match {
        case rational: Rational => new Rational(numerator, denominator)
        case abstraction: RationalAbstraction => new RationalAbstraction(numerator, denominator)
        case _ => throw new UnimplementedCaseException(this, "constructorImpl", first +: irationals: _*)
      }
    }
    else throw new MixingIRationalImplementationException(first, irationals: _*)
  }
```

question commit: https://github.com/axal25/LearnScalaMavenBasics/commit/c5a113b0361d8632bb39bbfc7ed7f7cd329a2da1
solution commit: https://github.com/axal25/LearnScalaMavenBasics/commit/1920128ba2aedac4fa9671311ec56dcc09dc7483

Comment: You will be calling the different operators from different locations and each location knows how many arguments are required, so overloading seems like a much better way to deal with this than a single varargs method. Also think about putting key operations in the `trait` and providing implementations in the concrete classes.

Comment: Maybe you want something like `def foo[R <: IRational](first: R, irrationals: Seq[R]): R` that way you ensure the varargs are of the same type at compile time, instead of throwing an exception in runtime. Anyways, it seems like you have some failed abstractions, you may want to learn more about OOP and rethink your design.

Comment: Like I previously stated, I recently started learning Scala. It's not exactly trivial for me to learn new Language and utilize correctly FP and OOP at the same time. At this point of time I don't really understand function definition you have written (I'm guessing it's a generic function), I'm improvising and trying to learn by tinkering. I'm focusing on learning Scala's caviouts (or rather basics). How do I call contructor of type R (with 2 parameters)?

Comment: @Tim I don't think implementing exactly the same way abstract methods of trait IRational makes sense. Obviously, I could define abstract method inside IRational `constructorImpl` and implement it inside Rational and RationalAbstraction but it would be dependent only on 1 argument. I think Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez's idea (if it's really generic method) is the best approach (in general). But right know I wanted to figure out varargs. I'm sure there will be time for me to learn about generics.

Comment: If you are just learning Scala then varargs is a bad place to start. I have answered the question here, so best to create a new question about other aspects of your solution. But I would not dismiss the idea of abstract methods too quickly as an idea, since they are the standard way to implement different behaviour for two subclasses of the same base class, which is what your code is doing.

Comment: @Jacek I would recommend you rethink your solution from the beginning or even the problem you wanted to tackle. Abstracting over multiple versions or irrationals sounds complex. If you want, open a new question focusing on the problem you wanted to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to write function that unwraps irationals: _* one by one and check the head's (first elements') type?

Yes, you need to check each element. `irationals` could contain elements of any subclass of `IRational` and they don't all have to be the same subtype, so you need to check each one. But it is not clear what the purpose of `irationals` is, so the question needs more detail.

Comment: Hi, I added edit to my question. I hope it clarifies the purpose of this function. Can you explain why matching does not work for varargs? If matching doesn't work - Do argument of the function type requirement work? You're saying that `irationals: IRational*` guarantees that elements of the sequence are of type IRational, but why `case rationals: Seq[Rational] => ` does not guarantee elements to be of type Rational.

Comment: Matching only works on types, and the fact that an instance of `Seq[IRational]` only contains elements of type `Rational` is not encapsulated in the type information. It is also not possible to match on the element type in a collection due to *type erasure*.